# Ng-Show called multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button with the ng-disable directive attached and a function to evaluate the button state. When the view loads, I notice that the function is called around 6-8 times. Is this normal? It's not only on load but any interaction with the view :

```
<button type="button" class="listBtn btn btn-xs btn-block btn-danger" ng-click="Site.deleteSite()" ng-show="Site.canDelete()"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i> Delete Site</button>
```

Then the controller has this function:

```
canDelete: function () {
    console.log(Site.selected);

    //CHECK IF SITE SELECTED
    if (Site.selected) {
        console.log('Site has been selected');
        console.log(Site.selected.children.length);
        //CHECK IF SELECTED HAS CHILDREN
        if (Site.selected.children.length) {
            console.log('Site has children');
            //SELECTED HAS CHILDREN - DISABLE BUTTON
            return true;
        } else {
            //SELECTED HAS NO CHILDREN - ENABLE BUTTON
            console.log('Site has no children');
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        //NO SITE SELECTED - DISABLE BUTTON 
        console.log('No site selected');
        return true;
    }
}
```

Also, if anyone has any recommendations for improving this or the IF statement that would be useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-show` will be evaluated on every digest cycle - it doesn't know (at that level of abstraction) what is checked inside `ng-show`, so must reevaluate anytime the result *could* have changed.  What you may want to do is something like:

```
 $scope.canDelete = checkIfCanDelete();
 checkIfCanDelete = function() {
     //your check
     $scope.canDelete = Site.selected && Site.selected.children.length;
 }

 $scope.$watch('Site.selected', function() {
     checkIfCanDelete();
 }
```

But honestly, if it's not computationally intensive (and this isn't), it's probably easier and clearer to just leave it as it.

Comment: I see what you mean. Okay, well if it's normal behavior I suppose it's fine to leave it. Thanks for the explanation.