# `ng-show` invoking function does not work

Tags: angularjs

In this [PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/82aiZZHiVIrYLmQM3hox?p=preview) I have a div with an `ng-show` element that invokes a `show()` function that returns false. Therefore, I expect the div not to be displayed.

Also, see that the `show()` function is invoked twice (the console.log shows the `sh` variable twice). How to fix this?

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('mydir', function ($compile) {

    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'EA';

    directive.scope = {
         control: '='
    };

    directive.template = '<div id="root"></div>';

    directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs) {

      var sh = false;     
      var wrap = angular.element('<div id="wrap" ng-show="show()"></div>');
      wrap.attr('sh', sh);  
      var wrapc = $compile(wrap)(scope)
      element.append(wrapc); 

      scope.show = function() {
        var elem = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#wrap' ) );
        var sh = elem.attr('sh');
        console.log(sh); // <-- should log false only once, not twice
        return sh;
      }


    };

    return directive;

});
```

HTML

```
<mydir></mydir>
```

Comment: Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025075/ng-show-called-multiple-times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem why the div is displayed is because you read the `sh` value from `attr` and by doing so it becomes a string.

```
wrap.attr('sh', sh);
```

This line actually sets the attribute `sh` to `"false"` (string) and not `false`. And then the get function `elem.attr('sh');` returns `"false"` as a string. And a not-empty string is truthy in javascript therefore it evaluates to true.

Replace:

```
 var sh = elem.attr('sh');
```

with a string comparison:

```
 var sh = (elem.attr('sh') == "true");
```

and it should work

That show is called twice is intended behaviour. Look here for details:
[Controller function getting called twice using ng-show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581170/controller-function-getting-called-twice-using-ng-show)