# service getting called multiple times

Tags: angularjs

Need a help with my service being called multiple times where as i am expecting it to be called only once. I could not find out why this is happening.

My html looks as follows:

```
<ul ng-app ng-controller="NCtrl" class="nav text-white">
    <li ui-sref-active="active" ng-show="findPageAccess('app.Cap', 'show')">
        <a ui-sref="app.Cap" class="auto" title="Dashboard">
        <i class="nav-icon">
        <i class="fas fa-tv"></i>
        </i>
        <span class=" single-line">Dashboard</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Within the controller file, i have below code

```
$scope.findPageAccess=function(url, variable){
    var acc;
    acc=AuthService.pageAccess(url, variable);
    return acc;
 };
```

So, when my html is loaded, i am expecting pageAccess function to be called only ONCE. However it is called around 8 times. i can see log message within pageAccess function printed many times.

I tried to debug but not successful in finding out why it is happening.
Any help/advice/pointers are greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: it's because of digest cycle, try `$scope.found = $scope.findPageAccess('app.Cap', 'show');` and `ng-show="found"`

Comment: Thanks Aleksey. I wrote the code in this because similar to the html code shown above, i have many other li tags for each of whom i am calling the findPageAccess with a different input.

if i have to pass it as a variable from controller, then i will need to define many scope variables inside controller.

is this the only way or there is any work around by which i dont need put many variables inside the controller? Please let me know.

Comment: `$scope.found` can be an array of booleans, if you are using `ng-repeat` you can potentially display it with `ng-show="found[$index]"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ng-Show called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025075/ng-show-called-multiple-times)

Comment: Thanks Aleksey. You answered my question

Answer (score 0):

Call service on `ng-init` then assign it's value to `ng-show`.